# how to get all value from same input id

Tags: php, jquery, html

jquery:

```
//value
var user_input = [];

$("#user_input").each(function() {
    user_input.push($("#user_input").val());
});
//test
user_input.push("hi");
```

heres the html:

```
City: <input id="user_input" type="text">
Month: <input id="user_input" type="text">
Year: <input id="user_input" type="text">
```

and my var_dump shows only:

```
    array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(2) "hi"
    }
```

the output should be:

```
    array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    [3]=>
    string(2) "hi"
    }
```

it looks like the jquery function dont loop at all.
hope this isnt illegal, posting too much question here :))

Comment: the negatives told me to do research first before leeching here :)
damn id haha @Boaz

Answer (score 4):

Change your HTML:

```
City: <input class="user_input" type="text">
Month: <input class="user_input" type="text">
Year: <input class="user_input" type="text">
```

JS

```
$(".user_input").each(function() {
    user_input.push($(this).val()); // you also had an error here, you should refer current field with this
});
```

ID must be **unique**. This is one of the most popular mistakes new developers make.

Comment: Is a class, `.` not `#` `user_input.push($(".user_input").val());`

Comment: @steve user_input.push($(".user_input").val()); this wont work as it takes only the first class

so i changed it to $this and it works fine now.. thanks

Comment: Yeah. you are right @MarkJeffreyCalvarioLopez. My mistake :) Just saw a `#` with a class and hurted me :P

Comment: i shouldnt use ids anymore @steve :)

Comment: @MarkJeffreyCalvarioLopez You should, but to select more then 1 element it's better to use classes.

Answer (score 1):

Ids are unique identifiers inside the DOM element. You should not use the same for more than one element.

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot use the same ID for multiple elements. From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) (emphasis is added by me):

> Each id value *must be used only once within a document*. If more than
>   one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID
>   will *only select the first matched element* in the DOM.

Try classes instead.